# Global name error is not defined even though it is

Tags: python, encryption

I keep on getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 21, in main
    translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content)
  File "encrypt.py", line 7, in encryptMess
    c = caesartranslate(content, mKey, myMode)
NameError: name 'myMode' is not defined
```

Even though I have already defined myMode in the code. I have checked my indentation and all is as they should be.

```
import time, os, sys, encrypt, caesarCipher, reverseCipher, vigenereCipher, glob

def main():
    inputFilename = 'frankensteinEnc.txt'
    outputFilename = 'frankensteinEnc.encrypted.txt'
    mKey = 5
    myMode  = 'encrypt'

    if not os.path.exists(inputFilename):
        print('The file %s does not exist. Exiting....' % (inputFilename))
        sys.exit()

    fileObj = open(inputFilename)
    content = fileObj.read()
    fileObj.close()

    print ('%sing...' % (myMode.title()))

    startTime = time.time()
    if myMode == 'encrypt':
        translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content)
    elif myMode == 'decrypt':
        translated = decrypt.decryptMess(mKey, content)

    outputFileObj = open(outputFilename, 'w')
    outputFileObj.write(translated)
    outputFileObj.close()

    print('Done %sing %s (%s characters).' % (myMode, inputFilename, len(content)))
    print('%sed file is %s.' % (myMode.title(), outputFilename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to get the code to encrypt a file using caesar cipher, vigenere cipher and reverse cipher but the code seems to be stuck on these three errors. Please help me

As @be_good_do_good suggested, I changed
     translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content)
to this
     translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content, myMode)

and this is my encrypt.py code

```
from  caesarCipher import *
from reverseCipher import *
from vigenereCipher import *

def encryptMess (mKey, content, myMode):
    c = caesartranslate(content, mKey, myMode)
    print('Output from Caesar Cipher\t%s') %c
    c1 = reverse(c)
    print('Output from Reverse Cipher\t%s') % c1
    c2 = vtranslate(c1,c, myMode)
    return('Output from Vigenere Cipher\t%s') % c2
```

After this I get this traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 21, in main
translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content, myMode)
File "encrypt.py", line 7, in encryptMess
print('Output from Caesar Cipher\t%s') %c
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: Your code may be indented properly, but the code in your question certainly doesn't appear to be, so please fix that first.

Comment: Also include the "encrypt.py" file, which is not std lib

Comment: `myMode` is a variable local to function `main()`, so it's not accessible from code in the `encrypt.py` module unless it's passed as an argument to something callable that's within it. "global" in Python generally just means _within_ the module that defines the item, **not** between modules.

Comment: @RoryDaulton please stop trying to guess the indentation of this code. There are clearly more indentation problems than just the first few lines, so it makes no sense for anyone other than the OP to do it.

Comment: @JimStewart I will double check but it is probably because I copy and pasted it here. Thank you however for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: @AdrianoMartins encry[t.py file has been imported into the main

Comment: @DanielRoseman as I said before, the actual code does not have indentation issues. also I have solved the code now. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either not passing the myMode to encrypt.py

pass it as below:

```
translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content, myMode)
```

and receive it in encrypt.py as below

```
def encryptMess(mKey, content, myMode):
```

Traceback you posted clearly says that encrypt.py does not have `myMode` defined. Atleast define `myMode` to some default value(like 'encrypt' or 'decrypt') in encrypt.py